# Google scripts : Multiple styles within a line of text in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, google-docs

I am quite new to Google scripts and javascript in general. I am doing the inventory of my grandpa's shop and my goal is to automate the creation of a catalogue (in google docs) with data from a google sheets. All I have done at the moment is fetch the data in the sheet with a script and put that information in a google docs with some simple text around it.

For example in my sheet I have information about an object (category, price, description, id, etc) and I would to like to display it like so in a google docs :

****ID** :** 1
**Category :** clocks
**Price :** 1000
**Description :**
...The first mechanical clocks, employing the verge escapement mechanism with a foliot or balance wheel timekeep...

The problem I have is that I dont know how to put the text in bold but the data from my google sheet in normal text. I guess my question is more how do I style text, that is on the same line, differently ?

[The result I want and the result I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGYjt.png)

I am using setAttribute but this puts the whole text in bold :

```
function mailMerging(){
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Surprise document');
var body = doc.getBody();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1V_3KwMQPNYagjJdfbas7VjyjodUt')
var sheet_values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
var nb = sheet_values.length;}

// Style pour décrire chaque objet
var style_objet = {};
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] =
  DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

// On va chercher les infos pour chaque objet 1 à 1
for (var c=1; c<nb; c++){

var categorie = sheet_values[c][0];
var marque = sheet_values[c][1];
var prix = sheet_values[c][2];
var description = sheet_values[c][3];
var id = sheet_values[c][4];

var text = body.appendParagraph("ID : "+ id +"\nCatégorie : "+ categorie +"\nMarque : "+ marque +"\nPrix : "+ prix +"\nDescription : \n"+ description+"\n \n");
text.setAttributes(style_objet);
}

}
```

Thanks a lot for reading my question and thanks in advance for any responses. This is my first post so I hope I did okay.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, `text.setAttributes(style_objet)` is used to `body.appendParagraph`. By this, the attribute is reflected to all texts. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. In order to achieve your goal, in this case, for example, how about putting the values of `ID :`  and `id` by separating and giving each attribute?

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var style_objet = {};
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

// On va chercher les infos pour chaque objet 1 à 1
for (var c=1; c<nb; c++){

var categorie = sheet_values[c][0];
var marque = sheet_values[c][1];
var prix = sheet_values[c][2];
var description = sheet_values[c][3];
var id = sheet_values[c][4];

var text = body.appendParagraph("ID : "+ id +"\nCatégorie : "+ categorie +"\nMarque : "+ marque +"\nPrix : "+ prix +"\nDescription : \n"+ description+"\n \n");
text.setAttributes(style_objet);
}
```

#### To:

```
var style_objet = {};
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
style_objet[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

// --- I added below script.
var style_objet2 = {};
style_objet2[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
// ---

// On va chercher les infos pour chaque objet 1 à 1
for (var c=1; c<nb; c++){
  var categorie = sheet_values[c][0];
  var marque = sheet_values[c][1];
  var prix = sheet_values[c][2];
  var description = sheet_values[c][3];
  var id = sheet_values[c][4];

  // --- I modified below script.
  [
    {title: "ID : ", value: id},
    {title: "Catégorie : ", value: categorie},
    {title: "Marque : ", value: marque},
    {title: "Prix : ", value: prix},
    {title: "Description : ", value: description}
  ].forEach(({title, value}) =>
    body.appendParagraph(title).setAttributes(style_objet).appendText(value).setAttributes(style_objet2)
  );
  body.appendParagraph("");
  // ---
}
```

#### Note:

- I think that in your script, `}` of `var nb = sheet_values.length;}` might occur an error when the script is saved. Please be careful this.